# unable to load libtesseract3051.dll 64 bit windows any issue in dependency

Tags: java, selenium, jar, tesseract

this is the issue i am facing it can anyone help me out ??

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract3051': Native library (win32-x86-64/[[libtesseract3051.dll]

please give some solution thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to mess with the source. Having the required JARs is sufficient.

[Development with Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/)